# Error when running QDB2 driver on deployment machine

Tags: c++, database, qt, db2

I am using *Win7* and *db2 express*. I have successfully compiled and used the db2 drivers on one of my machines, but when trying to use it on another computer that does not have db2 installed the driver won't run and return an empty string as an error.

Just to make sure I copied everything from **ibm/sqllib/bin** to a directory that can be found on the computer I use for deployment and dependency walker confirms that indeed the **qsqldb2** driver can find the libraries inside that directory.

Yet the problem remains and my app won't run properly, any ideas on how to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I am yet not sure if this classifies as an answer or not but, even though in my development machine it worked fine with the libraries inside **ibm/sqllib/bin**. The way I made it work on my deployment machine is by instead providing it with the libraries coming with the clidriver.